# Website displays blank in Chrome & Opera, but fine in IE10

Tags: google-chrome, browser, compatibility, localhost, internet-explorer-10

[This website](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/) has just moved web host.

It displays fine for me in IE10, but in Chrome and Opera it displays as a white page with a broken image.

If I clear my cache the same thing happens.

If I view the local copy of index.html in Chrome, it displays fine (with identical HTML code as the online version).

Why is the online version displaying incorrectly in Chrome, but the local version displaying fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page works fine for me in Firefox and Chrome. You will need to start narrowing down the issue. Since you have cleared your cache you can next try extensions. If you are feeling creative you can download a portable version of Chrome from PortableApps and see if it works in a clean version of the browser.

Google support also has a page of suggestions for such an issue  [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2457690?hl=en) if you wish to have a look. Suggestions include trying the page in Incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  The site loaded fine in incognito mode with extensions disabled.  After that the site loaded in the normal version of Chrome.  After that, the site loaded okay in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

I don't if this is directly related to your problem, but I have a few complaints about how you're setting the background for the page.

You're setting a background image for the `html` element, and then you're styling the `body` element. It may be better practice to leave the `html` element untouched and apply a background to the `body` element and do the rest of the styling on another container element if needed. One potential hazard, even if a bit far-fetched is that an extension, or browser, decides to make the `body` element have a solid white background, thus covering up your background.

The image is quite a heavy load at 616 kB. If it fails to load for whatever reason, or if it loads slowly, the user will not see the text against the default white background. I'd suggest putting a color as well in the background attribute, as a fallback.

Additionally, you're specifiying the background image as a relative URL, `../img/bg.jpg`, which might be a problem if you have a link structure more than two levels deep. In my opinion, it would be good practice to specify this as an absolute address instead of relative.

The latter two points would give a recommended code of something like:

```
background: #0a0102 url(/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```